# Best graph from dataframe with different conditions (groups and variables)

Tags: python, r, plot, group-by

I have a dataframe (cells) that it looks like this (it has more rows):

| ID | Time(min) | Cell1 | Cell2 | Cell3 | Cell4 | Cell5 | Cell6 | Cell7 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA001 | 0 | 10.57 | 77.28 | 14.11 | 15.12 | 1.56 | 95.83 | 3.41 |  |
| AA001 | 30 | 12.99 | 77.96 | 15.01 | 15.35 | 1.60 | 96.02 | 3.37 |  |
| AA001 | 90 | 11.41 | 79.85 | 16.69 | 19.65 | 1.28 | 92.14 | 6.01 |  |
| AA001 | 180 | 15.89 | 75.11 | 12.48 | 11.95 | 1.34 | 95.90 | 3.69 |  |
| AA001 | 360 | 10.16 | 83.67 | 19.51 | 14.68 | 1.09 | 70.80 | 26.21 |  |
| AA003 | 0 | 12.34 | 81.16 | 17.77 | 17.49 | 1.83 | 84.94 | 13.31 |  |
| AA006 | 0 | 21.71 | 71.24 | 7.67 | 11.43 | 1.56 | 90.03 | 7.62 |  |
| AA006 | 7 | 15.23 | 78.81 | 15.60 | 12.19 | 2.23 | 93.38 | 3.4 |  |

I have grouped by the variables ID and Time, because I would like to see the "evolution" of each cell for each sample:

```
inmune %>%
 group_by(PID, Time)
```

So, I have performed a scatter plot, but it's a mess with so many lines connected to each point.

Also I tried transform in a long-data format:

```
df2<- melt(cells, id = "Time")
```

But it results in a table with 3 variables (Time, cells, values) so I miss the ID.

The idea is to represent the difference of the values for each time, grouped by the ID.

But any suggestion about other type of graphs more suitable for this kind of data is more than welcome.
Thanks!!

Comment: What should be the x and y axis on your plot? Time and the value in the cell columns? If so what do you want to do with the info of which cell each value belongs to, and the info of the ID?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro in the scatter plot the X was time and Y the value, and for each ID was a different color. But the problem was that, with more than 60 different IDs, it cannot be visual. If you think in a particular type of plot I am all ears

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options separating the ID's in facets.

**Dummy data:**

```
df = tibble(ID = sample(letters, 300, TRUE),
            value = runif(300, 0, 40))

df = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Time = seq(0, by = 10, length = n())) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Obs: if your problem was the visualization of lots of ID's, it would've been better if you posted your whole data using `dput()`

**One facet for each group:**

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, value)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars(ID)) #try using scales = "free_x"
```

[image]

**Grouping several ID's in each facet:**

You can choose different concepts to group some ID's together, I choose the number of times they had data for, as that seems to vary in your data.

```
k = 9 #number of groups, change it as you please
facets = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(facets = ntile(n, k))

df = df %>% mutate(facets = facets$facets[match(ID, facets$ID)])

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, value, color = ID)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars(facets)) + #try using scales = "free_x"
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you'd like to see something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns

df1 = df.melt(id_vars=["ID", "Time(min)"], value_vars=["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3", "Cell4", "Cell5", "Cell6", "Cell7"])
df1["t"] = df1["ID"]+df1["variable"]

res = sns.relplot(x="t", y="Time(min)", hue="variable", size="value",
            sizes=(20, 800), alpha=.5, palette="muted",
            height=6, data = df1)
res.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I am trying to reproduce your code, but I receveid this error: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'melt' . As I'm not well familiar with python, I start like: 
import seaborn as sns 
df = open('Inmune_DA_Time_Plot.txt','r')

Comment: you are initializing your dataframe in a wrong way. what kinf of file is your `Inmune_DA_Time_Plot.txt`?

Comment: It is a tab separated file

Comment: then you probably need to do: `df = pd.read_csv("Inmune_DA_Time_Plot.txt", sep="\t")` first or something like this.

Comment: Great! I was doing something wrong. To visualize the plot, how can I do? because the output is: ```<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at 0x7fccc13f9370>```

Comment: solved: ```plt.show(res)```. Thanks!